# How to use the DC in a DC offset AC signal?

Tags: power

Many recreational vehicles have two sets of electrical wiring, one for AC power and one for DC power.  Is there a way to combine those lines so the AC has a DC offset and the DC appliances just use the DC?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes you can, but it would of course require additional circuitry, that can fail. Moreover AC is probably used for the motors while DC for electronics, probably power involved in the latter is 100+ times smaller than the former.

Comment: An example would be that I plug my laptop into the wall socket and somehow it uses the DC offset instead of converting the AC to DC and the inefficiencies that result from that conversion.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is completely impractical.
First, your computer can't just 'filter out' a 120VAC waveform on top of the DC.  You could actually do that, if you had a rather large choke, but that would be large and heavy and have to be connected between every outlet and 'DC Device' that you want to power.

For similar reasons, you would also need to have a large capacitive isolator to filter the DC out from any AC device you might want to power.  AC devices don't typically do well with a DC current on them, which you would have unless you blocked it.  To DC, a transformer or motor coil looks like a dead short.

Unless you completely filter out the unwanted component, your plugged in devices will fail, and sometimes spectacularly.